# Type Mismatch error when summing along one dimension in multi dimension array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 2D array and I am trying to add along one dimension. The 2D Array is of type variant and might have some of the elements as null ("")

Here is the code so far

```
'newArray is 2D Array
Function SumColumn(newArray As Variant, index As Integer) As Double
    Dim tempArray() As Double
    ReDim tempArray(1 To UBound(newArray))
    For i = 1 To (UBound(newArray))
        tempArray(i) = CDbl(newArray(i, index))
    Next
    SumColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(tempArray)
End Function
```

I get a type mismatch error when I am running the above code. Please help me debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probabaly getting a `Type mismatch` because `CDbl(newArray(i, index))` might actually not be a number.

This works for me. Please amend the code to suit your needs.

For demonstration purpose, I am storing an Excel range into a 2D array and then converting it to a 1D temp array. Once that is done, I am simply storing the relevant `Numbers` in the Double Array and finally calculating the sum.

Lets say that the worksheet looks like this

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyAr, TempAr()
    Dim dAr() As Double
    Dim n As Long, i As Long

    MyAr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10").Value

    TempAr = Application.Transpose(MyAr)

    ReDim dAr(0 To 0)
    n = 0

    For i = LBound(TempAr) To UBound(TempAr)
        If Len(Trim(TempAr(i))) <> 0 Then
            If IsNumeric(Trim(TempAr(i))) Then
                ReDim Preserve dAr(0 To n)
                dAr(UBound(dAr)) = Trim(TempAr(i))
                n = n + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(dAr)
End Sub
```

And this is the output

[image]